# Searching for a lost group member

Tags: hiking, search-and-rescue

Following on from [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/group-protocol-should-the-group-become-separated), what searching methods and techniques are best used in scenarios where a single group member (or perhaps couple of group members) become lost and separated from a group whilst hiking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience once a person(s) has been lost from the group first thing is to take a count of all members and ask when was the last time they saw the lost member(s). This will hopefully  set a timeline of when they became lost. Then use the following searches.

1. Retrace your steps, leave a member at where you started the search and if you have enough members leave one at any noticeable landmarks. If you do not have any means of communication set a time to regroup.
2. Start a comb search from the point the person was lost back to the location you noticed the lost member.
3. Start a radius search starting from the point the member was lost, move the center/distance of radius as needed.